# Why does std::vector allow the use of a throwable move constructor for the type it contains?

Tags: c++, c++11

Apparently, `std::move_if_noexcept()` will call the move constructor, even if it is not marked as `noexcept` if there is no copy constructor available.

From [cpprefeerence.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept) (emphasis mine):

> #### Notes
>
> This is used, for example, by `std::vector::resize`, which may have to allocate new storage and then move or copy elements from old storage to new storage. If an exception occurs during this operation, `std::vector::resize` undoes everything it did to this point, which is only possible if `std::move_if_noexcept` was used to decide whether to use move construction or copy construction. **(unless copy constructor is not available, in which case move constructor is used either way and the strong exception guarantee may be waived)**

As `std::vector` is using this function on reallocation, that could leave the vector and possibly the application in an undetermined state.  So, why would this be allowed?

Comment: Do you want quotes from the meetings where it was designed, or ways this benefits software?  Second, IIRC, these rules have changed over time.  What exact version of C++ do you want an answer for?  C++11?  I'm asking for you to narrow your question as much as possible.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, benefits, though quotes may help with understanding them.  If the rules have changed over time, then it might also be useful to understand it's evolution to it's current state.  Only marked this as c++11 as this is when it was introduced.

Comment: Do you have an alternative behavior in mind?  Should it simply be impossible to use `vector` with such types, whether or not it might be useful even without the strong guarantee?

Comment: @DavisHerring, if you don't have such a guarantee, then what happens? The new location with all of its elements that were moved are destroyed and the old location has some elements in it that are in a valid but undetermined state. So I guess no resource leak can occur, can it? And anything that could be referencing the vector would have to programmed with this in mind, which I guess is doable. Might be useful if the exception thrown is wrapped in another to say what range is invalid though.

Comment: @Adrian: You get the basic guarantee—the `vector` is in a valid but unspecified state, with no leaks, and you might be able to tell which element failed to move from the exception.

Comment: @DavisHerring, I didn't see anything in `std::vector` that states that you can tell which element failed to move.

Comment: @Adrian: No, I meant that you might have an exception thrown from your move constructor that identifies the move that failed.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you're doing what `vector` is doing when it would use `move_if_noexcept`. That is, you have some object `obj`, and you need to construct a new value of that type from `obj`. And after that, you're going to delete `obj`. That's a prime case for moving the object, so `vector` does that where possible.

If movement is `noexcept`, then moving `obj` is exception safe by definition. If it *isn't* `noexcept`, then you need to ask: what happens if the move constructor throws? What is the state of `obj` in that case? The answer is... you don't know. Even worse, what about the state from any objects you already moved from successfully? Can you move them *back*?

When it comes to copy constructors however, you *do know*. A copy constructor takes a `const&` to the source object. So by definition, a failed copy operation *cannot* modify `obj` (and yes, we know you can `const_cast`, but that makes your copy constructor a *lie*. Lies like that are why `auto_ptr` doesn't exist anymore, and I would guess that there's a blanket prohibition in the standard on lying copy constructors). So on a failed copy, `obj` is in its original state.

Therefore, if movement can throw, copying is preferred, as this provides the strong exception guarantee: in the event of an exception, everything goes back to the way it was.

However, if your only option is a throwing move, then you have two choices: make it so that such a type cannot *ever* be used with `vector`, or offer whatever exception guarantee the type itself offers on movement failure. And the latter is what is chosen.

It's allowed because *that's what you asked for*. Your choice of type doesn't allow for the strong exception guarantee, so it cannot be provided. But you can still make a `vector` of such types; you just need to deal with the possibility of non-copyable movement failure.

And since you're the kind of person who uses types that cannot provide a strong exception guarantee, you clearly must know how to handle these scenarios, right?

Comment: Don't particularly like that this is stated in the second person as if I had involvement in making this decision.  Should be reworded in third person unless the statement/question is specifically targeted at me, as it is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Adrian: "You" are the user. If the user is the one giving `vector` such a type, then that user... is you. I don't see why using the second person should be any different. If it makes you feel better, think of it as the Royal "you".